# Memberspaces may access private members of parent class

Tags: c++, idioms

I've been reading [this article](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1527), and was playing around with the memberspace idiom for a while when I noticed something that surprised me within this snippet (which compiles without problems: http://ideone.com/hRiV5B):

```
class HugeClass
{
    public:
        struct memberspace
        {
            int f() const { return parent.f; }

            private:
                friend HugeClass;
                explicit memberspace(HugeClass & parent)
                : parent(parent) {}
                HugeClass & parent;
        } memberspace;

        HugeClass() : memberspace(*this), f(42) {}

    private:
        int f;
};
```

I would have expected a compiler error that the access of `HugeClass::f` is not allowed because `f` is private in that context.

`HugeClass` is a `friend` of `memberspace`, so `HugeClass` may call the private constructor of `memberspace`, but why does it work the other way around without explicitly declaring `memberspace` a `friend` of `HugeClass`?

Comment: memberspace is considered part of the HugeClass and therefore has full access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By language rules in C++11.

> A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member.
> Example:
>
> ```
> class E {
>    int x;
>    class B { };
>    class I {
>      B b; // OK: E::I can access E::B
>      void f(E* p, int i) 
>      {
>         p->x = i; // OK: E::I can access E::x
>      }
>    };
> };
> ```

And in C++03 was

> The members of a nested class have no special access to members of an enclosing class, nor to classes or
> functions that have granted friendship to an enclosing class; the usual access rules (clause 11) shall be
> obeyed.

So, example from C++11 should not work with c++03 compilers.

Comment: Note that this is only officially the case since 2011. Older standards said the opposite ("The members of a nested class have no special access to members of an enclosing class"), although some popular compilers have been following the new rules for many years.

Comment: @MikeSeymour thanks. it is reason to read C++03 standard also before posting answer

Comment: That's very interesting. While looking for more information on this, I found the language defect report: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#45 From that document, actually I think it is valid in C++03 (not only C++11), because the original behavior was considered a language defect

Answer (score 1):

`memberspace` is part of `HugeClass` and has same access like other members of class.